# Postgresql: Timestamp from string

Tags: postgresql, function, date

```
 elseif (p_period = 'LAST2CALENDARMONTHS') then
        lMonthInt := 2;

        lLastDay :=  date_trunc('month',current_date - interval '1 month') + INTERVAL '1 month - 1 day' + (interval '1 day - 1 second');
        lFirstDay :=  date_trunc('month',current_date - (lMonthInt*INTERVAL '1 month'));

    elseif (p_period = 'LAST3CALENDARMONTHS') then
        lMonthInt := 3;

        lLastDay :=  date_trunc('month',current_date - interval '1 month') + INTERVAL '1 month - 1 day'+ (interval '1 day - 1 second');
        lFirstDay :=  date_trunc('month',current_date - (lMonthInt*INTERVAL '1 month'));
```

Using Postgresql, the above code converts a string into a FromDate and Todate, for example when I call **LAST2CALENDARMONTHS**

It will display
fromdate:
"2016-08-01 00:00:00"
Todate:
"2016-09-30 23:59:59"

I want to do the same for calling any month of the year, for example calling **JANUARY** the results should be:

fromdate:
"2016-01-01 00:00:00"
Todate:
"2016-01-31 23:59:59"

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get first and last days of January in current year use:

```
elseif (p_period = 'JANUARY') then
    lFirstDay :=  make_timestamp(date_part('year', current_date)::int, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
    lLastDay :=  lFirstDay + interval '1 month' - interval '1 second';
```

For PostgreSQL 9.3 and earlier, where `make_timestamp`doesn't exist, you can use

```
SELECT date_trunc('year', current_timestamp) + '0 months'
```

to get the first day of January.

Comment: I get this now:

Comment: ERROR:  function make_timestamp(integer, integer, integer, integer, integer, integer) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT make_timestamp(date_part('year', current_date)::int, ...

Comment: @Charlvanderbyl - You should specify Postgres version number (if historic). Thanks Laurenz.